# Angular 2 Pipe - Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined

Tags: json, angular, typescript, angular-pipe

I have a search pipe setup in angular 2 . The search pipe was working perfectly when i was on angular beta 14, now i upgraded to rc5 and the search pipe is broken and i get error. If i remove the pipe from the html code the products load. It is a generic search and filter pipe and should be used in many modules. Please help to resolve the issue.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined
at SearchPipe.compareWithAllFields (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:72117:57)
at Array.filter (native)
at SearchPipe.transform
```

**search.pipe.ts**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import {isObject} from "rxjs/util/isObject";
import {isEmpty} from "rxjs/operator/isEmpty";
import {empty} from "rxjs/Observer";
@Pipe({
    name: 'search'
})
export class SearchPipe implements PipeTransform
{
    transform(input, [searchString]:Array<String>)
    {
        if (input == null) return input;
        return input.filter(this.compareWithAllFields, searchString);
    }

    compareWithAllFields(value, index)
    {
        var fields = Object.keys(value);
        for (let i = 0; i < fields.length; i++)
        {
            if (value[fields[i]] != null)
            {
                if (isObject(value[fields[i]]))
                {
                    var childFields = Object.keys(value[fields[i]]);
                    if (childFields.length > 0)
                    {
                        for (let j = 0; j < childFields.length; j++)
                        {
                            if ((value[fields[i]][childFields[j]] + "").indexOf(this.toString()) !== -1)
                            {
                                return true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                if ((value[fields[i]] + "").indexOf(this.toString()) !== -1)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**list-products.component.html**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 form-group">
            <input placeholder="search product" class="form-control" type="text" #searchProduct (keyup)="0">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-6">
            <button [routerLink]="['/LoggedIn','Product','ProductAdd']" class="btn btn-lg btn-app">Add Product</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <h3>Products</h3>
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Sr #</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Category</th>
                    <th>Barcode</th>
                    <th>Unit</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th>Minimum Stock Level</th>
                    <th>Discount</th>
                    <th>Cost</th>
                    <th>Actions</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let product of products | search:searchProduct.value;let serial = index">
                    <td>{{ serial+1 }}</td>
                    <td>{{ product.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{ product.productCategory.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{ product.barcode}}</td>
                    <td>{{ product.unit?.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{ product.description}}</td>
                    <td>{{ product.quantity}}</td>
                    <td>{{ product.minimumStockLevel}}</td>
                    <td>{{ product.discount}}</td>
                    <td>{{ product.cost}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="delete(product)">Delete</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-default"
                                [routerLink]="['/LoggedIn','Product','ProductEdit',{id:product.id}]">Edit
                        </button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What should `this.toString()` return?

Comment: @usmanwalana I think `transform(input, [searchString]:Array<String>)` should be `transform(input, searchString)`.

Comment: @codef0rmer Your solution worked like a charm. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@usmanwalana, the PIPE API has changed since RC3/4, it now returns the 2nd parameter as a string rather than an array.

So change,

`transform(input, [searchString]:Array<String>)`

to

`transform(input, searchString)`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to change

```
return input.filter(this.compareWithAllFields, searchString);
```

to

```
return input.filter(this.compareWithAllFields.bind(this), searchString);
```

Comment: I tried this solution. The error went away but the search was not working. Solved it by changing transform(input, [searchString]:Array<String>) to transform(input, searchString)

Answer (score 0):

Solution :
Change `transform(input, [searchString]:Array<String>)` to `transform(input, searchString)`